# Timezone issue when date display in UI(show 1 day lesser) in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am facing one problem, which is related to different timezone.

In UI I have set the date with 3/11/18

**leaveEndDate -> 3/11/18**

in service I get result.

**leaveEndDate = "2018-03-11T06:00:00Z";**

But when I display the date in UI, its showing **"3/10/18"** but actual result should be **"3/11/18"**

It display 1 day lesser in the application.

I have change the Time Zone is -> Washington, DC - United States and it should work for all timezones.

1. Approach

   //Adjust the dates.

   ```
           NSDate* originalDateValue = [self valueForKey:actualKey];

           NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
           dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"; // tried formatter-> @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"; // yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ
           dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
           NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:originalDateValue];

           dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

           NSDate * actualDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

           [self setValue:actualDate forKey:actualKey];
   ```
2. Another approach which I used is:

//Adjust the dates.

```
NSDate* originalDateValue = [self valueForKey:actualKey];
NSDate* adjustedDateValue = [self.class adjustDate:originalDateValue forTimezone:[self timeZoneName]];

    +(NSDate*)adjustDate:(NSDate*)originalDateValue forTimezone:(NSString*)timezoneName
    {

    if([originalDateValue isEqual:[NSNull null]]) return nil;

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = ([[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timezoneName] secondsFromGMTForDate:originalDateValue] - [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate:originalDateValue]);

    NSDate* adjustedDateValue = [originalDateValue initWithTimeInterval:timeInterval sinceDate:originalDateValue]; //[originalDateValue dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeInterval];

    return adjustedDateValue;
    }
```

3. Third approach

   ```
   NSDate* originalDateValue = [self valueForKey:actualKey];
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
   [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
   NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:originalDateValue];
   NSDate* adjustedDateValue = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
   ```

Any help?

Comment: Pleas show the relevant code; how are you creating the `NSDate` and how are you showing the date in your UI.

Comment: The code here does not match what you state in your question. You claim you start with a date string in one format and you want to convert it to a new string in the local time zone. But your code does not attempt to do that all.

Comment: @rmaddy how could I resolve this issue?

Comment: You first need to update your question and clarify what you actually have and what you actually want. It’s unclear because your current code doesn’t match your current description.

Comment: @rmaddy I have update my question. Please cehck.

Comment: @Paulw11 please check the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`originalDateValue` is always being set to UTC time for the date you are giving it. `NSDate` works on UTC time since you aren't specifying a timezone. `dateFormatter` is converting the input you're giving it to your localtime, which is several hours behind. Since you don't specify a time, it's setting the time to 00:00:00 midnight, so when converting fro UTC to Washington DC, you're adjusting the timezone several hours behind.

You must adjust the source date according to the offset from UTC to `localTimeZone`:

```
NSInteger sourceUTCOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:originalDateValue];
NSInteger destinationUTCOffset = [localTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:originalDateValue];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationUTCOffset - sourceUTCOffset;

NSDate destinationDate = [initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:originalDateValue];
```

Then operate on `destinationDate` the way you have already provided.

Comment: [initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:originalDateValue] -> what is initWithTimeInterval ?

Comment: "Returns a date object initialized relative to another given date by a given number of seconds." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1414201-initwithtimeinterval?language=objc

Comment: Sorry but just about everything in this answer is wrong.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing your answer.